# SlideDown and SlideUp on HoverOut (quick basket)

Tags: jquery, shopping-cart, slidedown, slideup

I have a quick basket; a checkout box div that appears when you hover the basket link. I want the basket it to appear only on hovering over the link and it will disappear when the user moves away from the link.

The box should also stay still if the user is inside the main div and only slideout onmouseout too.

Pains me to post this I cannot get it and been at it for sometime..

## jQuery

```
// Toggle the Quick Cart (uses Load Balance for higher TPS no que!)
$('#show-quick-cart').hover(function () {        
    $('#quickcart').slideDown(500);
    return false;
});
$('#quickcart').mouseleave(function () {        
    $(this).slideUp(500);
    return false;
});
```

## HTML5

```
<a id="show-quick-cart" href="#show-quick-cart">MY BAG</a>
<div id="show-quick-cart-zone">
    <div id="quickcart" class="quickcart hide">
        <div class="quickcarttitle"><span>SHOPPING BAG</span></div>
        <div class="quickcart-products">
            <p><strong>No items in your cart so far</strong></p>
            <a href="/cart?ref=quick-cart"><img src="//gc-cdn.com/cart/securecheckout.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Demo

Live Demo (page)

http://tinyurl.com/bwn33op

The actual jQuery

http://tinyurl.com/cz6kl66

jsFiddle

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tBXa/11/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEMO on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2tBXa/21/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="pardiv">
<a id="show-quick-cart" href="#show-quick-cart">MY BAG</a>
<div id="show-quick-cart-zone">
    <div id="quickcart" class="quickcart hide">
        <div class="quickcarttitle"><span>SHOPPING BAG</span></div>
        <div class="quickcart-products">
            <p><strong>No items in your cart so far</strong></p>
            <a href="/cart?ref=quick-cart"><img src="//gc-cdn.com/cart/securecheckout.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>​
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#show-quick-cart').mouseenter(function () {        
    $('#quickcart').slideDown(500);
    return false;
});
$('#pardiv').mouseleave(function () {        

    $('#quickcart').slideUp(500);
    return false;
});

​
```

Comment: Your demo does not have the cart box staying still, it simply slides back up. If you read my question, it says, on the link, show the box, on link off, hide the box, however if they hover the link and are on the box - it shows the box until they move off the box.

Comment: in that case. you need to do change in html also. see the demo http://jsfiddle.net/2tBXa/21/

Comment: The `#pardiv` resolved this. Fantastic understanding and well solved. +1

Answer (score 1):

`onmouseleave` is not a valid JavaScript event, `mouseleave` is, just remove the `on`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/2tBXa/12/).

NB: [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) isn't a valid JavaScript event too, it's a jQuery one, so it needs 2 functions, one for the `mouseenter` event and the second for the `mouseleave`, so you should use `mouseenter` instead.

Answer (score 1):

### `.onmouseleave` is not a function in jQuery. It is [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

**EDITED BELOW** (After OP's Comment)

```
$('#show-quick-cart').on('mouseover mouseout',hover);
$('.quickcart').on('mouseover mouseout',hover);

function hover(e){
    e = e || event;
    var el = e.target || e.srcElement
       ,showel = $('.quickcart') //cache element to slide
    ;

    /* 
       test and set hoverstate of the element to slide
       note: because the sliding element contains more
       elements, we check for the originating element 
       *not* being the triggering element
    */
    if (!/show-quick-cart/i.test(el.id)) {
     showel .attr('data-ishovered',/over/i.test(e.type));
    } else {
     showel .attr('data-ishovered',false)
    }

    /* if image is hovered, no further action */
    if (/true/i.test(showel .attr('data-ishovered'))){return true;}

    /* only apply further hover handling to #NotificationSummary */
    if (/over$/i.test(e.type) && /show-quick-cart/i.test(el.id)){
       showel .slideDown();
    
    } else {
        /* use a timeout to allow the user to move over 
           into the image. If it's not hovered slide it up,
           otherwise, do nothing
        */
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (/false/i.test(showel .attr('data-ishovered'))) {
                showel .slideUp();
                showel .attr('data-ishovered',false);
            }
          }
        ,200);
    }
}
```

​

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/XqQHQ/) - (updated)

Comment: Your demo does not have the cart box staying still, it simply slides back up. If you read my question, it says, on the link, show the box, on link off, hide the box, however if they hover the link and are on the box - it shows the box until they move off the box.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: Sorry to misread your question, btw I've updated my answer according to your requirements.

Comment: thanks for the post but the solution is more simpler below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#quickcart').mouseover(function () {        
    $(this).slideUp(500);
    return false;
});
```